# jQuery - How to get two .text to work?

Tags: jquery, sum, var

This has managed to blow my mind over the past 4 hours, I just can't get it to work!

I have two functions replacing '.cd_price'. When you select B&W it works, but then when you change '.cd_quantity' it obviously gets replaced.

I have tried to put 'newPrice' into a hidden span, and grab that information from there, but that's as far as I can get without getting stuck.

You can find the example at http://gilliesaudio.co.uk/store/products.html

Thank you so much in advance guys! Hope I haven't missed any information.

**This is my HTML:**

```
<input type="text" value="50" min="50" class="item_Quantity cd_quantity">
<span class="item_price cd_price" data-base_price="0.53"></span>
```

**And this is my jQuery:**

```
$(".item_print-colour").on("change", function() {
        var base_price = $(".cd_price").data("base_price");
        var addition = (this.value == 'B&W' ? 0.20 : 0);
        var newPrice = (base_price + addition).toFixed(2);
        $(".cd_price").text(newPrice);
    });

/* CD START */
$(".cd_quantity").on("keyup", function() {
    var base_price = $(".cd_price").data("base_price");
    var discount = 0;

if (this.value > 99) discount = 0.09;
    $(".cd_price").text((base_price - discount).toFixed(2));

if (this.value > 199) discount = 0.14;
$(".cd_price").text((base_price - discount).toFixed(2));
```

Answer (score 0):

First, `$('.cd_price')` always returns a list of elements that have a class `.cd_price`. So when the dvd select is changed, it will replace the first `.cd_price` with the new price. And, in your demo page, I saw that the class of dvd price is `dvd_price`.

Comment: I have a separate function for each product.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are setting `base_price` to the `data-base_price` attribute inside the keyup event. You should be setting the variable to the current value of `.cd_price`. Something like the following:

```
var base_price = parseFloat($(".cd_price").eq(0).text());
```

This grabs the first instance of `.cd_price` since there are 2 and parses the text value into a float.

You might also then think about changing the variable.

Another issue I noticed was if you input a quantity value high enough to get a discount, the discount gets applied on each keyup event. Just thought I would point that out.